# Sqlite query to get search word with adjacent words too

Tags: ios, mysql, regex, sqlite, boolean-search

I would like to return the searched word including adjacent words which appear before and after the searched word using a query in SQLite. Is it possible to do this? Or should I attempt with another way?

E.g. for the below sentence (using the description column in the database table, column name is DESC):

```
> select DESC from TABLE_NAME where DESC like 'popular';
```

Which would return:

```
One of the most popular methods
```

But, I also want returned the two adjacent words "most" and "methods", like so:

```
most popular methods
```

I tried to check with REGEXP but the following are not working:

```
@"SELECT Desc FROM tablename WHERE LineText REGEXP '(^| )popular( |$)'"

@"SELECT LineText FROM table1 WHERE LineText REGEXP '[[:<:]popular[[:>:]'"
```

Can I get those with query or with other regular expression?

Comment: What does this mean:  "I want two adjacent words also "most" and "methods". from above text."?  Also, are you using MySQL or SQLite?

Comment: In MySQL, you can try `@"SELECT Desc FROM tablename WHERE LineText REGEXP '[[:<:]]popular[[:>:]]'"`. Also, you can check `@"SELECT Desc FROM tablename WHERE LineText LIKE '%popular%'"`.

Comment: @stribizhev, Yes I checked with this too earlier but it returns nil NSRegularExpression.. so may be anything wrong with syntax wise? not sure

Comment: @GordonLinoff This is the sample text in above question "One of the most popular methods". When user search for "popular" word I want "most" and "methods" words too. These both words appear in the sentence above.

Comment: In SQLite3, you can try using REGEXP like this: `@"SELECT Desc FROM tablename WHERE LineText REGEXP '\\bpopular\\b'"`. Does it work for you?

Comment: @stribizhev, Do apologize if I not explain properly, Yes this gives result but this gives all text of sentence. I want only required words as described in question. is it possible?

Comment: You need it for iOS, but I have only seen an example for Perl. In short, you need to implement your own function, like "capture", and then use it like `"SELECT CAPTURE('(\w+ popular \w+)', DESC) FROM TABLE_NAME"`. See example at http://www.ashleyit.com/blogs/brentashley/2013/11/27/using-regular-expressions-with-sqlite/.

Comment: @stribizhev Thank you very much. Let me check that how  it can help me for iOS if I go with same logic. Thanks again.

Comment: If you manage to write your own implementation, please post as an answer.

Comment: @Niks I think you're going about this incorrectly. You should be able to get the returned string using your `LIKE` statement, and then use the returned string to parse out the words using your templating system, or output stream.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going about this incorrectly. You should be able to get the returned string using your `LIKE` statement, and then use the returned string to parse out the words using your templating system, or output stream.